# Benefit of using RAM, or some form of internal memory on a FPGA

Tags: fpga, vhdl, programming, ram, spartan

I am at moment trying to store an image onto an FPGA. I calculated the space required by it to be 19200 kb, and are therefor wondering whether i should store it some other way than a 2d array?..  Or does the program i create automatically store the image i create in the RAM.. And what is the benefit of storing it in the RAM...

I not quite sure why i would/should store in the ram, rather than store it as an 2d array, what benefit do i have..  It only going to be used for a look up..

Comment: Look into the Xilinx Spartan Family Guides and you will see your picture won't fit neither into distributed RAM (LUTRAM) nor into BlockRAM. You will need to use an external RAM (SRAM or DRAM) to store such a big picture.

Comment: I am not sure.. kb => kilo bits note bytes, based on the dataseet it should be ok..  the fpga i am using is this http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds557.pdf

Comment: Fpga used : XC3S50AN

Comment: See Chap 4 of UG331 ([Spartan-3 Generation  FPGA User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug331.pdf)) titled Using Block RAM. Noting 19 kb is bigger than 18 kb the next question is what word width do you need?

Comment: i am not sure i understand what you mean by word width ?

Comment: First it is unclear if you are discussing ~19 kilobytes or 19 megabytes.  Next, you seem to be under the impression that storing something as an "array" would not require memory.  Really, your only choices within an FPGA are either the dedicated memory blocks, or else a "distributed" memory made up of the local storage in a large collection of logic cells.  Your little XC3S50AN is very limited in either option.  You should probably focus on *why* you are storing the image - are you buffering it for a display, or merely processing data which could possibly stream through without full storage.

Comment: I might have misunderstood something here.. 
Its like a representation of an image, its supposed to be  a lookup table which is the same size of the image, and  (x,y) position output a pixel value. I was under the impressing that storing an image using 2d arrays, would create  A lot unessesary logic, and thereby "waste" logic on handling that.. My idea with storing on a block ram would be to alleviate over usage of logic...  Each pixel contains 12 bits . 40 x 40 x 12 =  19200 bits.

Comment: So we are talking about 19.2 kb (kilo bits ~> 2.5 kB)? Your question is about 2.5 MegaBytes! As @user1155120 wrote, a Spartan BlockRAM contains 18 kB. So you'll need at least 2 BlockRAMs. The next question is: How many bits do you need per cycle for furthrr processing? 12?

Comment: I need to read 20 values each time..  so 20 x 12 ..

I am sure i getting where this is headed... Would i need to store it in a an external ram or ?

Comment: Fromt the data sheet :

"These elements are organized as shown in Figure 1. A dual ring of staggered IOBs surrounds a regular array of CLBs. Each device has two columns of block RAM except for the XC3S50AN, which has one column. Each RAM column consists of several 18-Kbit RAM blocks."

Comment: Could someone confirm that this is possible to do using the block ram in the FPGA?

Answer (score 1):

The second part of your question (2D array vs. RAM) really comes down to the resources available on your FPGA.  Usually storing something as large as an image or frame of video in logic elements isn't recommended, the logic that is created during synthesis will be huge and your compiler will take an age to fit it in the FPGA if it fits at all.  You should be able to get an idea of the complexity by running the first stage of compilation (in the world of Altera this is called Analysis and Synthesis) and then looking at the RTL viewer which will allow you to look at the logic graphically.

Using the RAM on your FPGA will give you a simple interface that can be driven with simple logic and this in turn will mean that the fitter will have easier time fitting it and the timing on your chip will improve.

If however you need more memory than is available then you will need to use external memory and even though there are memory controller IPs available this can be very complicated and problematic but if you need that much memory then this would still be better than implementing a huge memory array in logic.